# XQuartz El Capitan not setting $DISPLAY for a Vagrant built VM

Tags: x11, xquartz

I've built multiple VMs with Vagrant (CentOS, ArchLinux, Debian), all exhibit the same problem:

When I ssh onto the VM,

```
0;vagrant@archlinux: ~vagrant@archlinux:~$ echo $DISPLAY

0;vagrant@archlinux: ~vagrant@archlinux:~$
```

I've tried troubleshooting as explained here: http://www.xquartz.org/Support.html, but that didn't help.

I'm running El Capitan 10.11.3, XQuartz 2.7.8.

All I'm trying to do is to run `vagrant ssh -c 'xclock'` and have a window show up on my host OS.

Comment: I'm not an expert by any means, but just off the top of my head, is $DISPLAY being set locally by XQuartz/launchd (does 'echo $DISPLAY' print anything locally)? When you ssh, are you including '-Y' as a command line option? If you just installed XQuartz, you need to logout/login for $DISPLAY to be set, maybe try restarting. Also, as the FAQ states, X11Forwarding has to be enabled on the remote. Maybe step through the FAQ again just to make sure...

Comment: Yeap, I've tried all the above. $DISPLAY shows a value locally. I'm using `config.ssh.enable_x11_forwarding = true` to get a behavior similar to ssh -Y.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue but realized I never restarted OS X after installing XQuartz. Once I rebooted, XQuartz was correctly detected and X11 forwarding worked.